# repl.it node js Cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, replit

How do you set up a nodejs project on repl.it? I have a project that works on my localhost but once I uploaded it to repl.it it stopped working. Does repl.it automatically install packages from your package.json file? Is there something specific to my project that breaks it? Here is my code https://repl.it/@awestover/theland
The index.js script begins to run (I have a console.log in it) but the site just says, Cannot GET /
Is this because my index.html is in the wrong place?... 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. I forgot to upload my index.html file so there was nothing to serve as the default site. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you missed something when you copy-pasted it onto Repl.it.  You don't have any `GET` routes for `/`, which is why it's breaking with the message that it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yev from Repl.it here, if you go to all languages and then select Node.js, you should be able to start up a node.js repl that way. Or, if you prefer the straightaway link, here it is
https://repl.it/languages/nodejs